# UITableViewHeader keep(a part) always visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView with on Image inside the header. When the user scrolls up, the header scrolls out of sight. But I would like to keep the last 50 Pixels of the header always visible...

Is there a simple way to handle this?

Thanks,
Urkman

Answer (score 0):

in your tableView's delegate you can implement

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

(the UITableViewDelegate protocol extends the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol)

check that you've not scrolled too far and stop it there..